# Opening the test file in the Radare2 recording mode

Tags: radare2

I'm studying the radare2 utility (I installed it on Windows) and I wanted to edit the file with it. But an error constantly occurs:

```
[0x080486f5]> oo+
r_core_file_reopen: Cannot reopen file: C:\Users\User\Desktop\crackme\megabeets_0x1 with perms 0x0006, attempting to open read-only.
```

I don't understand what the matter is.

Comment: what version of r2 do you have? I've just tried on 3.9 for Windows and see no issue with opening in `oo+` mode.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was in the version. I updated and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to reverse-engineering.